# Passar dados para uma listview em outra Tela activity

Tags: java, android

Tenho um exercicio da faculdade, tenho que preencher campo nome,idade e cpf quando clicar no botao "cadastrar" ele envia os dados para outra tela activity onde será lsitados os nomes cadastros em uma listview, é nessa parte que travei.
Eu já fiz um array list a classe principal porem não sei como enviar esse araylist para outra tela para povoar o listView lá.

```
public class MainActivity extends MenuActivity {

private EditText nome,idade,cpf;
private Button btncadastra;
String  Nome,Idade,Cpf;
ArrayList<Pessoa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    nome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txNome);
    cpf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCPF);
    idade = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtIdade);
    btncadastra = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar);


    btncadastra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




            if(nome.getText().length() == 0){
                AlertDialog.Builder alertaNome = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertaNome.setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning);
                alertaNome.setTitle("Alerta");
                alertaNome.setMessage("O campo nome não foi preenchido.");
                alertaNome.setNeutralButton("OK",null);
                alertaNome.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                alertaNome.show();
            }
            if(cpf.getText().length() == 0){
                AlertDialog.Builder alertaCPF = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertaCPF.setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning);
                alertaCPF.setTitle("Alerta");
                alertaCPF.setMessage("O campo CPF não foi preenchido.");
                alertaCPF.setNeutralButton("OK",null);
                alertaCPF.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                alertaCPF.show();
            }
            if(idade.getText().length() == 0){
                AlertDialog.Builder alertaIdade = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertaIdade.setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning);
                alertaIdade.setTitle("Alerta");
                alertaIdade.setMessage("O campo Idade não foi preenchido.");
                alertaIdade.setNeutralButton("OK",null);
                alertaIdade.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                alertaIdade.show();
            }

             Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListaPessoa.class);

             Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
             pessoa.setNome(nome.getText().toString());
             pessoa.setCpf(cpf.getText().toString());
             pessoa.setIdade(idade.getText().toString());


            lista.add(pessoa);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Tela que lista as pessoas cadastrada:

```
public class ListaPessoa extends MenuActivity {

private ListView listaPessoas;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_pessoa);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    listaPessoas = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPessoas);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Ola,

A forma mais simples é fazer a classe pessoa implementar Serializable
apos isso salvar a pessoa na intent antes de chamar a outra activity

```
i.putExtra("pessoa", pessoa); 
startActivity(it);
```

Para recuperar na outra activity

```
    Pessoa pessoa = (Pessoa) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pessoa");
```

Comment: isso eu adiciono dentro do evento button?

Comment: O primeiro código voce coloca no button que chama a segunda activity
O segundo para recuperar o objeto pessoa pode ser no onCreate